How to run jar file in pop up and is it still possible
I want to run a jar game file in a pop up in a website using html and was wondering how to do and if it is still possible as I read that with require the use of java applets which are no longer supported in modern browsers. I would appreciate any help or guidance on the subject,
I have researched the topic a bit but I'm getting a little confused still and unsure how to proceed or if other coding languages should be used.

quick research shows that Applets were Java running inside web browsers. No current web browser supports that. so, as far as browsers go, java is thankfully dead and unable to run rampant viruses on the web

Everything old is new again.
